# IP address matching filter function

Tags: c++, windows, macos

I am writing code in C++ which runs both on windows and mac platform. I want to write a function which will accept machine IP address list and list of IP filters in CIDR format. This function will check if machine IP matches IP filter.

For example. If machine IP 10.210.177.47 and filter is 10.210.177.1/32
The function will check if 10.210.177.47 falls inside the filter range. 
Filter can also be Plain IP address like 10.210.177.45

i need to write a common code which can run on windows and mac.

Comment: Please specify **what you have done**, what works, what fails and what you don't understand in the **original post**.

Comment: What I don't understand is how to use mask in comparing IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to convert the mask length into a bit mask. E.g. a `/8` uses the upper 8 bits to identify the network and the lower 24 bits to identify hosts within that network. Hence, by shifting the IP address (expressed as `std::uint32_t`) left over 24 bits (`>>24`, you keep just the network part. For `10.210.177.47` within `10.0.0.0/8`, that leaves `10` - matches. For `/24`, it would leave `10.210.177` - no match.